# In Lone Wolf and Cub movie series is suckling not shown for censorship reasons?

Tags: lone-wolf-and-cub, baby-cart-in-peril

In the Lone Wolf and Cub movie, [Baby Cart in Peril](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_Wolf_and_Cub:_Baby_Cart_in_Peril), there is the character Oyuki who is a female vigilante with shocking tatoos. On her back is the mountain hag, and on her torso is the image of the son of the mountain hag, [Baby Kintaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kintar%C5%8D), suckling her breast.

In the manga on which the film is based, Baby Kintaro is actually suckling her left tit, but in the movie, the tatoo shown only has the baby "fondling" her breast, not sucking the tit. I don't understand this change. In other Japanese movies, even the Lone Wolf movies, I have seen live shots of babies suckling, so why would they shy away from showing a tattoo with a baby suckling a tit?

Comment: in one hand, we can be happy that it happened this way without blurring and pixelating like they usually do in a sensitive area ;)

Comment: I can imagine there is a difficulty to make the temporary tattoo last the kind it have to do for acting, maybe caused in the different skin texture...